# TFS Integration Platform Migration Issue

Tags: tfsintegrationplatform

I am trying to use TFS Integration Platform to migrate my project A on server 1 to project A on server 2.  I have branched code from project B on server 1 to project A on server 1 but I am not moving project B to server 2.  Is there any way that I can use a default action for all conflicts to resolve by adding instead of branching on server 2 during the migration?  If not, is there anything else I can do to get the code over from initial checkin without moving project B to server 2?

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: On a side note question: how did you create that branch image? Is it handmade or did you have a tool to generate it using TFS information?

Comment: Oddly enough I used Visio, just lots of custom objects and coloring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to move project A and project B, then do a `tf destroy` of project B.  This *should* create a new baseline for those branched files.

Try it first, though, in a test environment.

Comment: The problem is I am not a TFS admin on server 2, but I am on server 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming they are in the same project collection, in which case no - you will need to move all of A.